# Only some of the member classes of a tlb get registered

Tags: c++, registry, visual-studio-2003, typelib, midl

I had and an already existing odl file and I created the tlb out of it using MIDL.exe 
I registered the tlb using regtlib.exe when I search the registry I am able to find only the id of type library itself and the main dispatch interface, and I cannot find the rest of the coclasses and the interfaces and when I try to use them I get the "class not registered" error.
Note: I am using VC++ in Visual Studio 2003. I am able to view the tlb in VS's object browser window and it looks fine and has all the other member classes in it.

Answer (score 0):

Posting IDL and command line / flags that you use for MIDL would help.